# UIBarButtonItem displaced when style changed from plain to Done in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

When I change the bar button style from plain to Done, the button is moving towards the left direction.  This is happening only in iOS 7.

In the Interface Builder, I added a UIBarButtonItem to a toolbar and set its style as plain and identifier as custom and an Image.  Its width is set as 26.

When the button is clicked I'm changing its style to Done to indicate its in pressed state. In iOS 7 the button position is moving towards the left.  Anyone has any clue on this ?